# FileNotFound when using importlib and cx-freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze, python-importlib

I have a text file which I read using `importlib` as this:

```
read_text('spation.w2n.utils.data', 'mytextfile.txt', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

It worked perfectly until I decided to build and executable with `cx-freeze`. I have specified in `setup.py`'s `include_files` various alternatives that had not worked:

```
# Copy it to the root
("spation\\w2n\\utils\\data\\mytextfile.txt", ".")
# Copy it to the same folder 
("spation\\w2n\\utils\\data\\mytextfile.txt", 
 "spation\\w2n\\utils\\data\\mytextfile.txt")
```

The thing is, when I check the `build` directory, the file is in its correct place: `lib\spation\w2n\utils\data\mytextfile.txt`, but when running the app it seem not to find it. It finds it though, if I copy and paste the file into the root of the `build` directory, which I do not understand.

For clarification, this is the tree:

```
root/
    spation/
      - w2n/
          - __init__.py
          - utils/
              - __init__.py
              - data/
                  - __init__.py
                  - mytextfile.txt
    app.py
    build/
      - app.exe
      - lib/...
      - lib/spation/w2n/utils/data/mytextfile.txt # Does not work
      - mytextfile.txt # Here it founds it and the app works
      - spation/w2n/utils/data/mytextfile.txt # does not work
```

Comment: We need to understand how your prgram uses path. Is `build/` the same as `/build/` ? I'm not 100% sure because we do not have many of your implementation details, but the problem should come from relative/absolute paths. Try using an absolute path at first, then, work your way to make it work with relative paths. We also need to know if you are using a module, or if that feature is in your main program.

Comment: build is the folder `cxfreeze` creates. Give me a moment and I'll add more details.

Comment: Try doing `import sys; print(sys.path)`. It'll print you all the folders your current program has access to within the path.

Comment: But the program works well if I executed with `pyhon app.py`, the problem is the `app.exe` cxfreeze's generate

Comment: Is the paths in the `build/` directory correct ? Because if so, the problem might just come from the double slash `//`.

Comment: @IMCoins Ups that was a typo while writing the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198124/discussion-between-imcoins-and-elbaulp).

Comment: I cannot access chat from my place. So : Debugging paths from distance is kind of hard. We need to check the `absolute` paths at first. I invite you to both do in your program `import sys` then, `print(sys.path)`. And recompile your executable. Then, I invite you to use an absolute path, just to test (even if I'm 99% sure that the absolute path will work)

Comment: @IMCoins I managed to solve it, but without using `importlib`, just oppening the file with `with`

Comment: It seems you are missing an `__init__.py` file inside `spation` (unless it is a typo in your post). Anyway, opening the file using `with` is probably a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to leave it with `with`.